# cutting opendesk parts with fretsaw

Tags: furniture

I'd like to make opendesk for home use. I'd go with this project https://www.opendesk.cc/lean/studio-desk?config_id=9244#get-it-made

First I'd print the design plans on sheets of paper than transfer them somehow onto actual plywood.

Any advice on transfering printouts onto the plywood? Or perhaps there are better ways to do this process with fretsaw? (I don't have access to CNC machine)

Comment: I think using a fretsaw is a very difficult choice with probable poor results.  You will get much cleaner results with a circle saw and straight edge or a table saw.  Even a standard handsaw will cut the straight lines cleaner requiring less hand work to smooth out the jagged edges you will end up with using a fretsaw.

Comment: I agree with @Ashlar. Fretsaws have very thin blades, which make them good at cutting curves. This in turn makes them not very good at making straight cuts. In general, it is easier to make straight cuts with saws that have a deeper blade.

Answer (score 1):

> Any advice on transfering printouts onto the plywood?

You don't have to transfer the drawings if you can print them out full size, you can simply glue the printouts to the plywood, wait for the glue to dry and make your cuts. Then soak, scrape or sand the paper pattern from the plywood.

Sticking paper patterns directly to the wood is actually quite a standard way of doing some jobs in woodworking.

If you can't print the pattern out at full size then probably the best way to transfer the drawing to the plywood is via gridding. It's too difficult to explain this properly in words only so see the link below that shows the process more fully. But just to describe the process here in brief, you draw a grid of small square on the scale drawings, draw a grid of large squares on the plywood, then transfer your lines from the small squares to the large squares.

[How to Scale Drawings Using the Grid Method](http://www.wikihow.com/Scale-Drawings-Using-the-Grid-Method) on WikiHow.